# Math expression works in Google but not sqlite or KornShell.

Tags: sqlite, shell, math, ksh, arithmetic-expressions

I observed that math expressions in KornShell (ksh) or Sqlite don't have equivalent outcomes when comparing them to Google or Excel.

First put the expression below in Google:
8  / (8 + 3) * 9  = 6.54545454545

Now note the following in KornShell:

```
> ksh
> echo $(( 2 + 3 ))
5
>  echo $((8  / (8 + 3) * 9))
0
# Now change the first 8 to a 12 (higher than 11) and it works.... 
>  echo $((12  / (8 + 3) * 9)) 
9
```

Now note the same in sqlite:

```
sqlite> select 8/(8 + 3) * 9;
8/(8 + 3) * 9
0

sqlite> select 12/(8 + 3) * 9;
12/(8 + 3) * 9
9
```

How can I make this expression work in both KornShell and sqlite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sqlite has the notion of a datatype. All those constants - 12, 8, 3 - are integer constants. When making calculations with integers, it does not promote them to floating-point. Korn shell probably does the same. So would many mainstream programming languages, notably C and its numerous derivatives.

If you want floating point rules to apply, make your numbers floating point:

```
select 12.0/(8.0 + 3.0) * 9.0
```

Comment: yes, confirmed this is true for ksh (before seeing your answer). Good luck to all.

Comment: That's why application like BC and DC exist. If you whant the more precision (staying at shell level), change the order (keeping mathematical equivalence) of operation to have the biggest number divide and try to have the minimum of division occuring.

Comment: So to fix this, it looks like I need to cast as float or multiply by 1.0. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305613/converting-int-to-real-in-sqlite

Comment: Hmm, Adding "0.0" also appears to fix my expression:  8/(8 + 3 + 0.0) * 9  = 6.54  BUT  8/(8 + 3) * 9 = 0