# sqlite: mathematical operation doesn't return numeric, even though the cell is REAL

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, division

I have a `table` with three columns: `traffic INTEGER, revtraffic INTEGER, ratio REAL`.

When I update the ratio column in the following way:

```
UPDATE table
SET ratio = revtraffic/traffic
```

It returns 0.0 in all cells. However, if write:

```
SET ratio = revtraffic*100/traffic
```

then it displays the right results but obviously, 100x magnitude too much. What is going on?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305613/converting-int-to-real-in-sqlite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting int to real in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305613/converting-int-to-real-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`revtraffic` and `traffic` are integers, so dividing them will be done by [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), which returns only the "whole" part of the division (i.e, the part to the left of the decimal point). This result is then promoted to a `real` when you assign it to a `real`.

You can work around this problem by explicitly casting one of the arguments to a `real`:

```
UPDATE table SET ratio = (CAST revtraffic AS REAL)/traffic
```