# Retrieving float and binary data sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, blob

I have a database in sqlite

[image]

This database contains strings, floats and column with BLOB values. These BLOB values contain  binary data that it has to be converted to float numbers

I was wondering what is the most effective way to retrieve the data as if i try to retrieve all the required columns with only one query all the data become binary type

```
TDI %name of the variable. String
cn = _connect(file)  
cur = cn.cursor()  
query1 = f"""
                SELECT ST.Name || '.' ||EL.Name AS TDI,VA.Value,VA.CursorOffsetMS, EL.Scaling,VA.BlobElems
                FROM tblValues AS VA
                LEFT JOIN tblElements AS EL ON VA.fkElements = EL.Id
                LEFT JOIN tblStructures AS ST ON EL.fkStructures = ST.Id
                WHERE TDI = ?
                ORDER BY VA.CursorOffsetMs
                """  
    query2 = f"""
            SELECT ST.Name || '.' ||EL.Name AS TDI,VA.BlobElems,VA.BlobValues
            FROM tblValues AS VA
            LEFT JOIN tblElements AS EL ON VA.fkElements = EL.Id
            LEFT JOIN tblStructures AS ST ON EL.fkStructures = ST.Id
            WHERE TDI = ?
            ORDER BY VA.CursorOffsetMs
            """ 
cur.execute(query1,(TDI,))
float_data = np.array([(np.float(row[1]),row[2],row[3],row[4]) for row in cur.fetchall()])
```

Now I could do the same to get the blog values by executing query 2. But then I have to convert the data to float.

As I am not expert in databases I am asking cause there must be a more direct approach to get all the data at once and cast it properly. In the end I need to get all the numerical info as floats

I have been checking similar problems and the documentation from sqlite but so far I do not get anything clear.

Any info or tip is welcomed

Comment: I have previously used [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305613/converting-int-to-real-in-sqlite): `SELECT column*1.0 FROM mytable...`

Comment: How are the blobs encoding numbers?